# How to create a list with a random number of random integers in Python

Tags: python, list, random

I want to create a list that is a random length of randomly chosen integers. What I have so far is:
`a = [random.randint, random.randint, random.randint]` and it  goes on, but I want it so that it isn't however many times I typed "random.randint", but it uses the random function to generate a random number of random integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's what I would do:

```
import random
a = random.randint(0,100)
b = []
for i in range(0,a):
    b.append(random.randint(0,100))
```

Comment: This one makes a lot more sense, especially because I never learned random.sample and how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code, bunch of `random.randint` and on single `random.sample`:

```
import random
l=[random.randint(0,100) for i in range(100)]
print(random.sample(l,random.randint(0,100)))
```

Output:

```
[27, 44, 80, 95, 54, 41, 52, 26, 21, 26, 91, 92, 10, 85, 13, 62, 30, 45, 0, 24, 58, 11, 95, 17, 0, 29, 37, 66]
```

Answer (score 1):

i think that will solve your problem choice

```
s = [random.randint (0, 100) for i in range(5)]
print (s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy if you're planning on a large scale (it will be faster than list comprehension)

```
import numpy as np

your_list = list(np.random.randint(0,100,n)) # n is the list size.
```

You can do away with `list` if you only need an `iterable`.

Comment: I am not sure if he wants NumPy